# /icons/icomoon.woff files 404 not found en Cloudways

Tags: php, laravel, css3, error404

No puedo visualizar los iconos de icomoon en producción porque devuelve un error 404

> GET /icons/icomoon.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET /icons/icomoon.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Los ficheros están en la ruta correcta: public/icons y funciona en mi máquina local pero no en mi servidor de cloudways.

Tengo el siguiente css en public/icons/style.css:

```
font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:
    url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('icomoon.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

He tratado de solucionarlo poniéndolo de esta forma:

```
  src: url('icomoon.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('icomoon.woff2') format('woff2');
```

Pero no ha funcionado.

También lo he intentado poniendo las siguientes líneas en public/web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

Y tampoco ha funcionado.

Comment: Traduce al español por favor

Comment: El archivo /icons/icomoon.woff esta en el servidor en dicha carpeta? puede que este dentro de una carpeta /assets/ y la referencia no esta correcta. Probablemente necesites compilar los assets para produccion `npm run production` https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, los de cloudways tienen deshabilitada la ejecución de los .woff, tan sólo hay que abrir un ticket pidiendo que la habiliten.